# Store table heading titles `THEAD` as jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, syntax

I'm trying to store the value (different for each tabe header column) of `<th>` as a variable in jQuery, how can I do this? I'm using a jQuery plugin called simpletip which creates the effect I want, but since I have 14 columns each with different titles, I want to store the title for each one on a "foreach" kind of basis but I'm not sure which direction to go... help?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            $('thead th').simpletip({

                var title = $(this).html();

               // Configuration properties
               content: '<div class="info"><span><span>$title</span></span></div>',
               fixed: false
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youve almost got it already...

```
$('thead th').each(function(){
   var th = $(this);
   th.simpletip({
      fixed: false,
      content: '<div class="info"><span><span>'+th.html()+'</span></span></div>'
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  THat's exactly what I needed!  I knew I was close.